# I want to be able to make a three person winners circle

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I basically want three people to stand on three different pressure plates. I want them to somehow all connect in a way that when they are all activated it sets off TNT. I don't want the TNT to set of with just one person.

Comment: AND Gates connected together.

Comment: An even cooler idea: use the example in the answer, but replace the TNT with a dispenser filled with fireworks!!!

Comment: @Kaleb, What on earth you you want to do that for?

Answer (score 9):

This is a really simple thing. As seen in the following screenshots, you just have to negate the pressure plate signals, then negate the combined signal and voilà, the TNT is fired off only when all are powered.

[image: Triple AND gate]

This uses the fact that the last torch will only be activated if *all three previous torches* are inactive - which they only are if all three pressure plates are active.

Comment: Good job, that is a great idea!